# How to reschedule containers with swarm when the server dies for a moment

Tags: docker-swarm, swarm

I run two servers using docker-compose and swarm

When stopping the A server,  the container in A server is moved to B server.

but, when starting up the A server, the container that was in the B server will not moved to A server.

I want to know how to properly arrange the location of the dead server's container when the server dies for a moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for your Swarm to be able to re-create a task when a node goes down, you still need to have a majority of manager nodes still available... so if it was only a two node Swarm, this wouldn't work because you'd need three managers for one to fail and another to take leader role and re-schedule the failed replicas. (just a FYI)

I think what you're asking for is "re-balancing". When a node comes back online (or a new one is added), Swarm does nothing with services that are set to the default replicated mode. Swarm doesn't "move" containers, it destroys and re-creates containers, so it considers the service still healthy on Node B and won't move it back to Node A. It wouldn't want to disrupt your active/healthy services on Node B just because Node A came back online.

If Node B does fail, then Swarm would again re-schedule the task on the next best node.

If Node B has a lot of containers, and work is unbalanced (i.e. Node A is empty and Node B has 3 tasks running), then you can force a service update which will destroy and re-create all replicas of that service and will try to spread them out by default, which may result on one of the tasks ending up back on Node A.

`docker service update --force <serivcename>`